# Enable SharePoint 2013 Workflows

Tags: development, workflow, sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint 2013.

To activate Out of Box Workflows in SP2013 we generally activate these features that are mentioned below:

1. Workflows.
2. Three-state Workflow.
3. SharePoint 2007 Workflows.
4. Publishing Approval Workflow.
5. Disposition Approval Workflow.

Now, these features only limit till SP2010 Workflows.

Such as while creating workflows the following SP2010 along with the additional workflows are present in the dropdown list:

1. Approval - SharePoint 2010
2. Collect Feedback - SharePoint 2010
3. Collection Signatures - SharePoint 2010
4. Disposition Workflow
5. Publishing Workflow
6. Three-state

My question is, how to get SharePoint 2013 Workflows in this list of Workflows?

Is there any feature that is required to activate?

or

Is any installation required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to configure workflow for SharePoint 2013
as well Workflow manager. 
Follow the steps given in below article to make it up and running.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx

Comment: I followed these steps.. My workflow management site in IIS says its forbidden...
Furthermore, when I deploy a SP 2013 Workflow it gets displayed normally but cant see it in the list's workflow settings to be associated..

Comment: Check workflow management site has administrator rights or not? as well go to services and check Service Bus Gateway and Service Bus Message broker service is running or not. if all is good, something related to the security certificate at your end

Comment: The logged in user is the same that was configured as the user during Workflow Manager Config.

Service Bus Gateway & Service Bus Message broker services are running smooth.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Seems like you have used farm admin or any other admin user in "workflow manager configuration" wizard in configure service account section. if it is the case, then you need to create a new user for service account and reinstalled the Workflow Manager first remove the software and every single piece related to wf manager